# Custom WP_Query with no posts to output

Tags: customization

I have created a custom WP_Query as seen below. The query works well except for when $favorites is empty. When $favorites is empty, the query still outputs posts, which I don´t want. It could seem like it defaults back to the standard WP_Query to output all published posts.

Anyone knows what´s going on?

```
$favorites = wpfp_get_users_favorites($user = '');
$favorites_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $favorites));

while ($favorites_query->have_posts() ) : $favorites_query->the_post();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty argument here does not equal logical *in nothing*. It equals no value to process and so WP ignores it and goes further as usual.

Just wrap your query in `if( !empty( $favorites) )` condition.